# is jquery flash plugin can be used for playing any video

Tags: video, jquery-plugins

I would like to play any video not only youtube in this jquery flash plugin , can i play any video.
and if any other video player i can use ?

Please suggest .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

For playing FLV in html, you should use the  tag. For example:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
width="320" height="240" 
wmode="transparent" 
data="player.swf?file=video.flv&autoStart=false">
<param name="movie" 
value="player.swf?file=video.flv&autoStart=false"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
</object>
```

Player.swf is player swf file and filename is the file attribute.